# Turn Windows Phone Settings On/Off

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

OK What I need to do is fairly straightforward : Be able to **programmatically** (via some API) turn system settings on/off, like :

- WiFi
- Bluetooth
- Cellular
- FM Radio

Any ideas on how to go about that? (I've searched everywhere and found nothing up-to-date)

Comment: you can't change device settings programmatically, the only thing you could do is to show those settings

Comment: You have mentioned FM Radio in your question? Did you get the solution for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change them programmatically in Windows Phone, but you can ask a user to change them and redirect a user to the `Settings` page (for this purpose use `ConnectionSettingsTask` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394011(v=vs.105).aspx).

Comment: Is there any code on How to open FM Radio like these settings as user mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 6):

you cannot change the settings through code but you can direct the user to the settings page by using the following navigation statement .

in this it will navigate to settings location page ..
from this you can set location settings

similarly you can go to wifi and other settings

var navigate = Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings-location:"));

Answer (score 1):

You can't actually change them programmatically. However, you can determine if they're enabled or not, and send the user to the appropriate settings page to enable/disable themselves.

Comment: How can I Know if they're enabled or not?

Answer (score 1):

Use ConnectionSettingsTask class and use below code to launch setting page for changing settings -

```
 ConnectionSettingsTask connectionSettingsTask = new ConnectionSettingsTask();            
 connectionSettingsTask.ConnectionSettingsType = **ConnectionSettingsType.WiFi**;
 connectionSettingsTask.Show();
```

ConnectionSettingsType is an enum which have all four properties which will navigate you on corresponding setting page.

Hope this will help